# Unable to Use MPS to Run Pre-trained Object Detection Model on GPU

Tags: python, macos, cpu, yolo

I am using MAC and trying to run Ultralytics YOLOv8 pre-trained model to detect objects in my project. However, despite trying to use MPS, I am still seeing the CPU being used in torch even after running the Python code. Specifically, the output I see is: "Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.43  Python-3.9.16 torch-1.13.1 CPU".

I wanted to know if has support for MPS in YOLOv8, and how can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "--device mps" as a parameter when running the command line